# Можно ли использовать шаблонизатор Django для обычного текста?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Хочу выводить список товаров в заказе в админке в виде таблицы. Товары - это атрибут модели Cart, которая связана с моделью заказа (Order). Я получаю QuerySet товаров и из него хочу сформировать таблицу. Можно конечно сделать что-то примерно такое

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def products(self, obj):
        qs = obj.cart.items.all()

        t_body = ['<tr><td>{}</td></tr>'.format(prod.name) for prod in qs]

        return format_html('<table>' + t_body + '</table>')
```

В принципе это работает, но настоящая таблица сложнее и это дико неудобно. Можно ли использовать для этих целей обычный шаблонизатор? Я знаю можно задать функции `render` аргумент `content_type='text/plain'`, но как в итоге сделать, чтобы все это в админку попало?

Comment: В Django можно переопределять шаблоны админки https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates Возможно это как-то поможет вам

Comment: @Andrey я нашел решение, посмотрите мой ответ. Что думаете по этому поводу? Нормально или это плохой вариант?

Comment: [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)

Comment: @andreymal О, спасибо, так гораздо лучше)

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров насчет правильности решения затрудняюсь ответить, мало опыта в этом.

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу вот так:

```py
def products(self, obj):
    ctx = {'products': obj.cart.items.all()}
    table = render_to_response('orders/product_in_order.html', content_type='text/plain', context=ctx).content.decode('utf-8')
    return format_html(table)
```

1. Использовал render_to_response, а не render, т.к. этой функции не нужен request.
2. content выводит результат, но в виде байтов b'\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b'
3. Поэтому перевел их в строку с помощью decode('utf-8')

Лучшее решение от @andreymal без изобретения велосипеда:

```py
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def products(self, obj):
    ctx = {'products': obj.cart.items.all()}
    table = render_to_string('orders/product_in_order.html', context=ctx)
    return format_html(table)
```